# How to override database settings in Django tests?

Tags: django, transactions, pytest, pytest-django

I'm on Django 1.8 (using pytest) and I have the following configuration:

- A `default` and a `readonly` database managed by a `MasterSlaveRouter` that directs DB calls to one connection or the other depending on whether they're read or write operations.
- In my development environment, both entries in the `settings.DATABASES` dictionary have the same setup (they just use a different connection, but the database is the same).
- In my test environment, however, there's only a `default` database.
- I have a `post_save` signal fired whenever a model `Foo` is saved.
- I have an atomic operation (decorated with `@transaction.atomic`) that modifies a `Foo` instance and calls `.save()` on it twice. Since no custom `using` parameter is passed to the decorator, the transaction is only active on the `default` database.

The `post_save` callback creates a `Bar` record with a `OneToOneField` pointing to `Foo`, but only after checking whether a `Bar` record with this `foo_id` already exists (in order to avoid `IntegrityError`). This check is done by performing this query:

```
already_exists = Bar.filter(foo=instance).exists()
```

This is ok the first time the `post_save` callback is called. A `Bar` record is created and everything works fine. The second time, however, even though such a `Bar` instance was just created in the previous `Foo` save, since filtering is a read operation, it is performed using the `readonly` connection, and therefore `already_exists` ends up containing the value `False` and the creation of a new record is triggered, which eventually throws an IntegrityError because when the create operation is performed on the `default` connection, there is already a record with that `foo_id`.

I tried copying the `DATABASES` dictionary from dev_settings to test_settings, but this broke many tests. I then read about the `override_settings` decorator and thought it would be perfect for my situation. For my surprise, however, it didn't work. It seems that at some point, when the application is initiated, the `DATABASES` dictionary (the one only with `default` from the test_settings) is cached and then even though I change `setting.DATABASES`, the new value is simply not accessed anymore.

How can I properly override the database configuration for one specific test?

Answer (score 4):

Hum... well if you are using only pytest, I think you'll need to cleanup your databases after tests.

Now, to override django settings, it's good to :

```
from django.test import override_settings
@override_settings(DATABASE_CONFIG=<new_config>)
def test_foo():
    pass
```

You should try the pytest-django:

```
pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_foo():
    pass
```

When you run your tests, you can set the create-db param, to force py.test create a new database or if you want to reuse your db, you can set the reuse-db, like:

```
$ py.test --create-db
$ py.test --reuse-db
```

checkout:
[Oficial docs](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html)

Comment: Warning: I believe the docs point out that the mechanics of `override_settings` is such that it won't necessarily work as expected for certain types of settings; notable mention: *database settings*.